# How can I Update fullname in COntact in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I want format of fullname like Title + First Name + Last Name.but this type of format is not avalilable in System settings.so,I just want to update fullname not first name or last name.How can I achieve this requirements.

Comment: Fullname is actually derived from the fields firstname + lastname and cannot be edited itself. Thus, if you edit firstname and/or lastname seperatly it will reflect on the fullname field.

There is a field for title i CRM if I recall correctly, why not use that together with the fullname field instead?

Also, what is the context in which the customer is going to use the information?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can't change the format of full name in the database [aside from the formats CRM defines as options](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-update-full-name-format-in-crm.html).  But, you do have two options:

1. Create a Select plugin that updates the value of the full name on the entity (if you're using early bound, the property will still be read-only, but you can edit the value in the attributes collection directly with no issues.)  This could potentially be a really bad performance issue since selecting 1000 entities requires the plugin to run a 1000 times.  I'd probably recommend the next option:
2. Create your own field `new_fullname`.  And make the format whatever you want.  Setting it with a Create/update plugin, as well as potentially through the JavaScript.  Then it's just updating your forms, views, and any plugins / workflows that currently reference fullname.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if i understand what you want archive in settings i don't know any way, if have some solutions: plugin, workflow or javascript. You can add in onchange event of firstname, fullname and title and change fullname. Something like that:

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fullname").setValue(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("firstname").getValue() + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lastname").getValue());
```

EDIT: I forgotten that is readonly you can change readonly using Javascript like that:

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fullname").setSubmitMode("always");
```

See here another [option](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.pt/2011/07/how-to-update-full-name-format-in-crm.html).

Comment: I have checked and find that fullname is readonly property and thats why I cant update it using workflow and PlugIn.

Comment: Pedro : This is fine for the visuality but the value is not going to save in the database.have you checked it?

Comment: Sorry... The fullname field has a different behaviour, you can follow the alternative way.